# What's with my Toyota Tercel after I jump started another person's vehicle?

Tags: toyota, battery, jump-start

I jump started my daughter's vehicle which is a 6 cylinder with my Toyota 4 cylinder. Will that affect my Toyota car?

I'm not sure if it was a existing problem and jump starting it made it worse. Because my car battery looks like it still holds a full charge and my car still starts. What could have happened or what could it be cause, my car seemed to slip into gears a bit. And I just discovered the shake and sputter is only when it's in gear.

Comment: Automatic/manual? Make/model/year? Current maintenance done? What else can you tell us about your exact issue? Not much info to go on. If it still starts fine, jumping another car had no affect on your vehicle.

Answer (score 4):

The new symptoms are VERY probably not related to the jumpstart, especially if you didn't have any "spark incidents" during the jumpstart. One quick doublecheck: At night, turn your headlights on without starting the car. It helps to have a white garage door or something similar to reflect your headlights. Note how bright they seem, and their color - orange, yellow, white, bluewhite. Now start the car and let it idle. Do the headlights DARKEN or become redder, or did they BRIGHTEN and become whiter? Give it a little gas - not a lot, just a bit. Again, did the headlights darken towards red, or did they brighten towards bluewhite?

If starting the car & giving it gas makes the headlights brighten towards bluewhite, your charging system is working just fine. If they get darker/redder, your alternator is NOT charging your battery... which MIGHT POSSIBLY be enough to make your car run poorly, but only if the battery is now dangerously low.

Open the hood & doublecheck your spark plug cables. It's possible that one of them got bumped or tugged during the jumpstart. If your "Check Engine" light is on, get the OBDII codes from a scan tool.

It's not at all inappropriate for a 4cyl car to jumpstart a 6cyl car. I've jumpstarted a semi (no lie) with a VW. Had to connect to it twice, once for each of the semi's batteries. A LITTLE vehicle can easily jumpstart a HUGE vehicle.

Comment: Or you just have a multimeter. Then check the voltage of this two cases: engine off and engine on. The voltage of the second one should be higher.

Comment: Testing change in brightness only applies to traditional halogen/resistive technology headlights. The HID lights on my Q45 do not change in brightness or color with a change in RPM. However, my brights are still halogen type, so the test would be appropriate if the brights are used. That said, if the car has been started and driven many times, which the question seems to imply, and the car still starts at all, then likely the battery and charging system are just fine.